# How do I resolve the "commits ahead/behind" messages using Tower?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git, Github, forking, pull requests, etc... and that's why I am using the Tower app for Mac.

I forked [this repo](https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents), made changes, submitted a pull request, had it accepted and was successfully able to update my local code with the master changes.

But I still have this text in [my own repo](https://github.com/datafeedr/crawler-user-agents):

***This branch is 3 commits ahead, 1 commit behind monperrus:master.***

What do I need to do in the Tower app or on Github in order to resolve that message?

Everything else seems OK so I'm not sure why I'm seeing the *"commits ahead/behind"* message.

Thanks,

Eric